# Select last two records per customer in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can you anyone show me a query for the following scenario?
I have these columns in table `access_log`:

```
customer_id |  service_name | accessed_time
```

A customer might have accessed the service any number of time. But I need to list only the last two records for each `customer_id`.

Comment: Are you looking for the last two (i.e. two most recent) for each `customer_id` regardless of the `service_name` or is the `service_name` involved somehow?

Comment: ya.. two most recent records for each customer_id , never mind about service_name

Answer (score 12):

[Window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/tutorial-window.html) to the rescue (again):

```
select customer_id, service_name, accessed_time
from (
    select customer_id, service_name, accessed_time,
           rank() over (partition by customer_id order by accessed_time desc) as rank
    from access_log
) dt
where dt.rank <= 2
```

This assumes that "last two" means "the two most recent". The `row_number` window function might be more appropriate depending on how you want to handle duplicates.

Given data like this (sorry, I'm not feeling that imaginative tonight):

```
=> select * from access_log order by customer_id, accessed_time;
 customer_id | service_name |    accessed_time    
-------------+--------------+---------------------
           1 | one          | 2011-01-01 00:00:00
           1 | two          | 2011-01-02 00:00:00
           1 | three        | 2011-01-03 00:00:00
           2 | two          | 2011-01-02 00:00:00
           2 | one          | 2011-04-01 00:00:00
           2 | three        | 2011-05-03 00:00:00
```

the above query yields:

```
 customer_id | service_name |    accessed_time    
-------------+--------------+---------------------
           1 | three        | 2011-01-03 00:00:00
           1 | two          | 2011-01-02 00:00:00
           2 | three        | 2011-05-03 00:00:00
           2 | one          | 2011-04-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Nice! Probably, you'll need to partition by `customer_id, service_name`. The way the OP phrased their question, it looks as though this statistics is supposed to be on a per-customer AND per-service basis...?

Comment: @Lukas: The OP does say "only last two records for each `customer_id`" so I don't think `service_name` enters into it except as something to display. I'll see if I can get a clarification.

Comment: Hmm... I was confused by the *the* in "*might have accessed the service*"

Answer (score 5):

Something along these lines should work:

```
select * from access_log a1
where 2 > (select count(*) from access_log a2
           where a1.customer_id = a2.customer_id
           and a1.accessed_time < a2.accessed_time)
```

This reads: get all logs for which there exist 0 or 1 other access logs for the same customer with a later "accessed_time". Be sure to have appropriate indexes on relevant columns.

Comment: Nice usage of the WHERE-clause. Never thought about anything similiar.

Comment: @bos: Thanks. Albeit, I think *mu is too short*'s solution might outperform mine

Comment: Optimal pre-windowing suggestion.